# Need help organizing text in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

First time here, I need help organizing an inputted text file in Python

The text file contains basketball team names, their conference, and wins/losses
Example:

`Miami (FL)    (Atlantic Coast)   32 5
UCLA          (Pac-12)       32 5
Fresno St.    (Western Athletic) 25 8`

I need these created into objects of:

`team_name
conf
wins
losses`

My problem is the diverse format these come in, for instance, Miami (FL) is a name, some names contain two strings, others contain one. Some conferences contain one string or two, and in the Miami example, the name contains parenthesis. I can't figure out any good way to sort these because they're all so different. Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: Are your input variables separated by tabs or a bunch of spaces? If you use tabs then `thelineyouarereading.split('\t')` should give you a list of what you want from that line.

Comment: @Hoog Yes the numbers are separated by tabs, but not the teams and conferences. I think I figured out a way to do it using the tabs and then re-splitting on parenthesis and going off of length, thanks for the help!